# Overloading implemented virtual function

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class `Foo`

```
class Foo{
  public:
     bool virtual bar(){return false;}
};
```

And class `FooFoo` inheriting `Foo`. `bar()` is not overriden in class `FooFoo`. I cannot change the headers of `Foo` or `FooFoo`. Is it then at all possible to override the default implementation of `bar()` in `FooFoo`?

Comment: In addition to the answers given here, you could use the "Decorator Pattern", which does not directly provide an answer to your question but rather an alternative approach to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it then at all possible to override the default implementation of
>   bar() in FooFoo?

No, but you could derive another class, and use that class "polymorphically" via the base. This should have the same effect, given that the original client of Foo does his work through the interface of Foo, as he should

Therefore:

```
//In Foo.h - may not be modified
struct Foo
{
  virtual bool bar(){ return true;}
};

//In FooFoo.h - may not be modified, hence no override...
struct FooFoo: public Foo
{
  virtual bool bar(){/**/}
};

//FooFoo_2 - The new class - may be implemented in terms of FooFoo
struct FooFoo_2: public Foo
{
  virtual bool bar() override{/*new implementation*/}
};

void fooUser( Foo& foo )
{
  bool result = foo.bar();
  if (result ){} //etc
}

int main()
{
  FooFoo_2 theNewImplementation;
  fooUser( theNewImplementation );
  return 0;
}
```

Note also that "override" is not required, but if added, one would get a compiler error if the signature of bar changes in base (which would cause derived to not be virtual anymore) - something that one would want to be aware of.

Regards

Comment: You missing inheritance and `FooFoo` should not override in your example.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible; you can't modify a class without modifying it, as it were.

Your best option is probably to publicly inherit from `FooFoo` and override in the derived class.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can only override a function by declaring the override within the derived class's definition.

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll need to declare the override in the `FooFoo` class definition, which you said you cannot do. If you tried to define the overriden function in `FooFoo`, outside of the class, you'd run into errors, since it was not previously declared to be overriden in `FooFoo`.

Also note, in C++11 and later, you should use the `override` attribute. Example:

```
struct FooFoo : Foo
{
    bool bar() override { return true; }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In C++ language no. In particular implementation it is technically possible to manually modify vtable for class `FooFoo` and replace pointer to `Foo::bar()` to something else. Of course this would be an ugly hack and neither recommended practice in any sense nor guaranteed to work even when something changes (for example compilation flags).